# Using Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a virtual machine to 'simulate' a remote server

Tags: 18.04, remote

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a virtual machine(VMWarePlayer), my main OS is Windows 7.

It is possible to 'simulate' a remote server on the VM, connecting from Windows 7.

I want to do some practical tests/learn without having a real remote machine, like connecting thru SSH, accessing databases remote, remote python etc.

--
The VM(guest) and the Win7 are on the same computer(same network).

I know how to connect to a server like Digital Ocean using SSH;  I want to connect to to my VM like it was on a server not on my computer.

If it is possible, how ?

Comment: Step 1: Search your VM documentation for how to run the Guest headless. Step 2: Use SSH to connect to your headless server.

Comment: Yes it is possible. It is also extremely common. You install Ubuntu Server on the virtual machine and then when you run the VM is actually *is* a server.

Comment: @AlexP, I know VM is a server, but how that I simulate is remote, connecting to it to SSH, using IP, keys

Comment: It *is* remote. It is a different computer, with its own IP address etc. It just so happens that you can *also* use your keyboard and screen to interact with it; but this is simply for convenience.  Just ignore the VMware Player window, minimize it, and use only the tools which you would have available for a virtual private server from DigitalOcean or whatever.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a tutorial on how to use SSH. There are already many such tutorials. What is different about your setup that requires yet another tutorial?

Comment: @user535733 ; no the VM(guest) and the Win7 are on the same computer(same network). I know how to connect to a server like Digital Ocean using SSH;  I want to connect to to my VM like it was on a server not on my computer.

Comment: @user3541631 that's called "SSH" and it works the same way whether it's a VM locally on your computer (with a private IP address) or a remote server in a datacenter five hours away from you.  It's still considered 'remote' even if you SSH to its local IP address.  If you have the server in a VM, run `ip -4 addr list`, get the IP address from the system, and then from your Windows 7 host, open PuTTY and SSH to that IP address you got from the system.  (I do this all the time with VMs and such even locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a VMware Player virtualized server there is several modes of network connection. They are configured in the Network Adapter section of the virtual machine settings:

- Bridged: The VM is independent and have to get its IP address manually or thru a DHCP server in the same network as the host; the server is visible to other hosts.
- NAT: The VM uses the host IP address of the host to communicate to
  the net, but the server is only visible to its host.
- Host-only: The VM can only communicate with and is visible to its host.

So, to make connections to the server from its host in the NAT/Host-only modes, use the local IP address assigned to it by the WMware Player. In the Bridged case, you should use the IP address assigned by DHCP o manually by you.

The easiest to use is NAT; the IP address assignment is automatic and the server can connect to the internet for updates, download packages, etc.

Get the server IP address in the VM terminal using the command `ip a`:

[image: VM get IP address example]

In this example, the IP is *192.168.177.130*; to connect by ssh use the puTTY ssh client to that IP or the [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) command (change *user* to your username):

```
ssh user@192.168.177.130
```

To check a local page if the server has a web server, go to *http://192.168.177.130* in the host's browser, connecting to the server's MySQL  engine in 192.168.177.130 port 3306, etc. Verify that the server's firewall allows the connection to the service you want.

To use a domain name like *myserver.testing*, add the server's IP and desired name to the `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. Edit it with `notepad` launched as an administrator (Press Windows key, write *notepad* and launch it with right click/run as administrator) and add the line (change to your IP and name):

```
192.168.177.130  myserver.testing
```

Save it and you can use the name as in *http://myserver.testing* in your host's browser.